# Probability Urn problem - application of Bayes thm

Tags: bayes-theorem

I am learning statistics and I am trying to solve this problem:

Players A and B draw balls in turn, without replacement from and urn containing three red and four green balls. A draws first.  The winner is the person who draws the first red ball. Given that A won, what is the probability that A drew a red ball on the first draw?
(Bartoszyński, 4.4.7)

So given from this information, I suppose I am asking what is the probability $\mathbb{P}(A_1)$ given $\mathbb{P}(A_i)$

> $A_i:=\{\text{red drawn on i-th turn}\}$
>
> $\mathbb{P}(A_1|A_i)=\mathbb{P}(A_i|A_1)\mathbb{P}(A_1) / \mathbb{P}(A_i|A_1)\mathbb{P}(A_1)+...$
>
> I have found the probabilities of individual draws
>
> $\mathbb{P}(A_1)={3\over7}$
>
> ...
>
> $\mathbb{P}(A_3)={3\over 3}$

I have tried more, but I don't know what all to put in the denominator.

Could you please give me at least a hint?

Comment: @G. Sassatelli Your edit is problematic

Comment: @GregoryGrant Sorry, my hand slipped on Shift+Enter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $E = $ the event that A wins and $F = $ the event that A draws a red ball on the first turn. Then 
$$P(F|E) = \frac{P(E|F)P(F)}{P(E)}$$
$$P(E|F) = 1$$
$$P(F) = \frac37$$
$$P(E) = \frac37 + \frac47*\frac36*\frac35 + \frac47*\frac36*\frac25*\frac14*\frac33$$

Comment: Thanks, this is the kind of hint I needed. I was calculating P(E) in a wrong way